# PDF export extent of 600 polygons in QGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, pdf

Within one polygon shapefile, I have 645 features spread across the UK which I need PDF plans of. The plans do not need to be scale specific, just so long as the extent (plus a 40px padding to show some of the surroundings) is shown.

The closest thing I've found to achieving this is the plugin Maps Printer. Except I don't have time to create 646 unique print layouts, I want to use one.

The process I have in my head is to select row 1 in the attribute table, zoom the canvas to the selected feature, then set the map (in the print layout) to the canvas extent, then export and repeat for row 2, 3 etc...

The name of the PDF would be defined by a field in the attribute table called "Title No".

Comment: Do you really need to use PyQGIS for automation?  Or were you just assuming you'd need to go that route?  If you don't need to use python, use the out of the box "Atlas" solution mentioned by @TeddyTeddTed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an Atlas, there's a good tutorial here: [Lesson: Creating Detailed Maps with the Atlas Tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html)